# How to switch to a tabbar item in the "More" View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm programming an app in objective c for Iphone/Ipad. I have some items in the "more" of the tabbar. I want to switch to one of those views. How can i do it? Normally i would use selectedIndex, but it doesn't work on the "More" tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select view controller from more screen you should select more view controller first as it displayed in previous answer:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController: [tabBarController moreNavigationController]]
```

And then perform pushViewController method for more view controller

```
[[tabBarController moreNavigationController] pushViewController:neededViewController animated:NO]
```

Or use the better way:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController: neededViewController ]
```

Comment: how do i find the neededViewController? If i create a new one (Home *homeView = [[Home alloc] init]; [tabBarController setSelectedViewController: homeView ];) xcode during runtime tells me "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected." Home is a View controller managed by the uitabbar

Comment: You can choose selected view controller only if it contains in tabBarController.viewControllers array.
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:neededIndex]]

Comment: thank you! This code works perfectly! Can i ask you to add it (modified as you like) to your answer to made it more complete? 
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController:  [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:7]];

Answer (score 1):

```
[myTabBarController setSelectedViewController: viewControllerThatYouNeed];
```

**Edit:**

Try to use selectedViewController property of UITabBarController.
From Apple Docs:

> Blockquote
>   In iOS 3.0 and later, you can use this property to select any of the view controllers in the viewControllers property. This includes view controllers that are managed by the More navigation controller and whose tab bar items are not visible in the tab bar.

Comment: this leads to the more view. if i want to go to an item that is inside the more view?

Comment: i cannot get the code to select the right view controller.. If i create a new one (Home *homeView = [[Home alloc] init]; [tabBarController setSelectedViewController: homeView ];) xcode during runtime tells me "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected." Home is a View controller managed by the uitabbar