# Handling the MoreNavigationController programmatically in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I've noticed a difference in the Swift and Objective-C implementation of UITabBarController.

In my application I want to programmatically select a tab when a button is pressed. In objective-c, I can simply set the SelectedViewController of the TabBarContoller to be the view controller at the index I want.

```
UINavigationController* navController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];

[self setSelectedViewController:navController];
```

However, when selecting an item that would appear in the MoreNavigationController in swift, the result is

> only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected

This makes sense because:

- Overriding the setViewControllers method in Objective-c; after the
  super call completes given seven elements, self.viewControllers is an
  array of length seven.
- Overriding the setViewControllers method in Swift; after the super
  call completes given seven elements, self.viewControllers is an array
  of length four.

My question is, am I missing something? Is there a reason in swift it truncates to the first four entries, and is there something I can do to make it behave more like the objective-c TabBarController?

[How to switch to a tabBarItem in the "more" view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637357/how-to-switch-to-a-tabbar-item-in-the-more-view) is the most relevant question I've seen, but the selected answer does not seem to hold for Swift.

Comment: You must have a bug in your Swift code. The choice of language should not change the behavior unless the code is written to do two different things. You really should update your question with the relevant Swift code.

Comment: To give you hope, I think you may have found a UIKit bug, or you and I share the same bug in our code. Can you post your code @J_llama?

Comment: @PaulWoodIII Unfortunately I can't, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in tests projects. 
After some hunting, the issue seemed to be isolated to the tab bar controller setup in our iPhone storyboard. It didn't happen on our iPad storyboard with an identical setup, which is why it took me so long to track down. The final solution was to copy our iPad setup to the iPhone and tweak things :/ So I never got a real resolution to this

Comment: I gave up setting the viewControllers as well. My current solution is to have two tab bar controllers and have my app delegate (for the moment) switch the two tab controllers bars as needed. Some of the Tab Bar's  viewControllers are shared. My only concern would be how this implementation would work on a more memory intensive app.