# Open More Navigation Tab in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uihostingcontroller

I have a `UIHostingController` which contains my SwiftUI `View`. I want to return to the More Tab from the `UIHostingController`.

I tried calling

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which doesn't work. I tried changing the tabbar's selection, but this of course never goes to the more tab.

```
self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 5
```

I presume there is an easy function to make it pop up over my view, I just can't find it.

Edit:
To explain further, I have a storyboard with several `ViewControllers`. One is a `UIHostingController`. Perhaps that detail doesn't matter, I am trying to open the list of 'more' items from a `ViewController` with Swift. The `UIHostingController` though uses a custom navigation, so the default back buttons aren't relevant.

Update:
The closest code I have found is:

```
 self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = tabBarController?.moreNavigationController
```

This however did not appear to work, but by calling the code below. I was able to flicker show the moreViewController.

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: If you work with `UIHostingController` in UIKit environment it has nothing to SwiftUI content... it just a view controller.

Comment: Alright, I removed the SwiftUI tag for the second time. I did not add it the first time.

Comment: What is the relation between `self.tabBarController` and `UIHostingView`? Please add more relevant details.

Comment: There is no UIHostingView, the UIHostingController is just another tab on the TabBarController

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637357/how-to-switch-to-a-tabbar-item-in-the-more-view

Comment: @koen that looks like the code that should work, I put it in and nothing changed. I'll dig some more at this issue because that code is what I assumed the code should be.

Comment: I actually set the tabBarController to moreNavigationController.popViewController and it flickers between my current controller and the moreViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered it. This is how you return to the more controller, which is just the root view.

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented the **tabView** but in SwiftUI the boilerplate code is like below:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selection = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection){
        Text("First View")
            .font(.title)
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("first")
                    Text("First")
                }
            }
            .tag(0)
        Text("Second View")
            .font(.title)
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("second")
                    Text("Second")
                }
            }
            .tag(1)
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
 }
}
```

Here you can see the **selection** is 0, if you change it to 1 it will go to second tab when you open the view. Hope this help

Comment: No I am still using Storyboard, and I have a UITabBarController implemented. My 8th tab goes to a UIHostingController. Which is a method for slowly migrating to SwiftUI. For this I am looking for a Swift answer, not a SwiftUI answer. Thanks though!

Comment: Your question says "SwiftUI". So please update your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I guess leaving in SwiftUI is good because people familiar with SwiftUI will understand UIHostingController best. Made a small tweak to improve.